# How to correctly replace printf with sys_write?

Tags: linux, assembly, 32-bit, intel-syntax

I'm making new post about the same program - I'm sorry but I think that my question is much different than the previous one. My program gets 2 parameters at the start - number of repeats and a string. Number of repeats determines how many times should the last word from string be printed. For example:

```
./a.out 3 "ab cd"
```

shows in output

```
cdcdcd
```

I already made ( with Stack users help :-) ) a working program using call printf. It works for 0-9 number of repeats only but it's not as imporant as the main thing - my question is how to replace this "call printf" with sys_write calling.

I got information that I have to compile this using

> -nostdlib

option but it doesn't matter if my code isn't correct. I tried my best and I also found some information about possible methods here but I can't make it work properly.

Printing new line works good but I have no idea how to deal with string from parameter #2 connected with sys_write. It would be great if someone more experienced find some time and point out what I need to change in the code. It took some time to get through the "call printf" version but then I was able to experiment and now I'm totally lost. Here it is:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.globl _start
.text

_start:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ecx, [ebp + 4] # arg1 int ECX 
    mov ebx, [ebp + 8] # arg2 string EBX
    xor eax, eax

# ARG1 - FROM STRING TO INT
atoi:
    movzx edx, byte ptr [ecx]
    cmp edx, '0'
    jb programend
    sub edx, '0'
    mov ecx, edx


## =========================== FUNCTION =========================== ##  

# SEARCH FOR END OF STRING
findend:
    mov dl, byte ptr [ebx + eax] # move through next letters
    cmp dl, 0 
    jz findword
    inc eax
    jmp findend

# SEARCH FOR LAST SPACE
findword:
    dec eax
    mov dl, byte ptr [ebx + eax]
    cmp dl, ' '
    jz foundwordstart
    jmp findword

# REMEMBER SPACE POSITION, CHECK COUNTER >0
foundwordstart:
    push eax # remember space position
    cmp ecx, 0 # check if counter > 0
    jz theend
    jmp foundword

 # PRINT LAST WORD
foundword:
    inc eax 
    mov dl, byte ptr [ebx + eax]
    cmp dl, 0
    jz checkcount
    push ecx
    push eax # save current position in word
    push edx
    push ebx

    lea ecx, [ebx+eax] # char * to string
    mov eax, 4 # sys_write
    mov edx, 1; # how many chars will be printed
    mov ebx, 1 # stdout
    int 0x80

    pop ebx
    pop edx
    pop eax
    pop ecx
    jmp foundword

# decrease counter and restore beginning of last word
checkcount:
    dec ecx # count = count-1 
    pop eax # restore beginning of last word
    jmp foundwordstart

theend:
    pop eax # pop the space position from stack
    jmp programend

# END OF PROGRAM
programend:
    pop ebp

    # new line
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,offset msgn
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80

    # return 0
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80


.data
 msgn:   .ascii "\n"
```

It's also really strange for me that I can run it with:

```
    mov ecx, [ebp + 12]
    mov ecx, [ecx + 8]

    add ecx, eax # char * to string
    mov eax, 4 # sys_write
    mov edx, 1; # how many chars will be printed
    mov ebx, 1 # stdout
    int 0x80
```

and it works well - but only if I don't use -nostdlib (and of course I have to change _start to main)...

Comment: You already have the address as `ebx + eax` that's what you should pass to the syscall, e.g. `lea ecx, [ebx+eax]`

Comment: @Jester thanks for helping me another time ^^ I changed "mov ecx, [ebp + 12], add ecx, 8, add ecx, eax" to "lea ecx, [ebx+eax]" but now I get memory protection violation. And I'm confused that it works only with stdlib - I thought that disabling stdlib is just about replacing "call printf"

Comment: That's unrelated issue, caused by accessing the arguments wrong (I think I have told you already...) PS: learn to use a debugger (I bet I have told you that too)

Comment: I just remember you told me about my bad method with popping dl and msg, maybe I missed something or just didn't understand. Sorry, I'm feeling really stupid with assembly... Why am I accessing the arguments wrong? What's the point? I thought if it works with stdlib it should work without it, too. I didn't change anything in access I think - I just replace printf. Will debugger called ALD be good for me?

Comment: It doesn't work the same, no. `main` gets arguments as per the C calling convention, `_start` gets arguments as per the ELF specification. Slightly different.

Comment: Ok, so I try to get my counter with mov ecx, [ebp + 8] (first argument) and string with mov ebx, [ebp+12]. I think it's good but I still get memory violation...

Comment: Note that first argument is the program name. You actually need 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: I updated my code to current "version". I know that first is the program name. My friend sent me quite different program but using arguments and he reads first argument using [ebp+8] and it works well. Anyway, changing it to [ebp+12] doesn't make things better. I think there's something I don't understand. To make matters worse, I can't install ald...

Comment: It did make it work for me. Your updated code is totally wrong, you even removed initialization of `ebp`.

Comment: I just followed his code that seems to be working, sorry. Update one more time, still doesn't work. Can you give me some concrete tips? It shouldn't be too hard for me if you could make it work in couple of minutes...

Comment: More concrete? I already told you what to do. Your current update uses `ebp+4` and `ebp+8` no idea where you got those from... should be `ebp+12` and `ebp+16`. Of course you claim that didn't work for you. It does for me.

Comment: Ok it's too much assembly for me today... I accidentally changed something in code on my computer and that was the reason why it didn't work... My bad, sorry that you had to waste time for such a moron like me :D Thanks for help

Comment: looks like linux, so you should certainly have `gdb` available from official repositories. You may search also for some GUI front-ends for `gdb`, but I don't have very good experience with those, never got impressed by them... while I had also hard time to remember controls of `gdb`... but if you will learn it, you can use it for whole GNU world (works for debugging of C/C++/D/go/Java/Fortran/... other compilable languages, usually found in `gcc` compiler collection), so it's not just Assembly thing. Check bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for gdb starting hints.

Comment: Oh, and I did want to answer the question from title. The SO type of answer is "close the question with 'too broad' reason", the `printf` is actually mammoth piece of software delicacy, fine tuned over decades. If you use it like `printf("abc");`, you could have simply used `puts` instead, the "f" in "printf" stands for "formatted" and that's the reason why it would take hundreds (probably even thousand+) of lines to produce exact full replacement of `printf` in Assembly, and I'm not even talking about some performance tricks, just shortest simplest correct implementation.